# When rolling friction increases with speed, why traction is less at highspeed?

Tags: friction

We know that rolling friction on car tyres directly proportional to the square of the speed, so at high speeds 
As rolling friction is more why traction force is less?

Comment: Why do you believe that "rolling friction" is the same as the static friction between the tire contact patch and the road?

Answer (score 1):

Rolling friction is completely different to the friction between the tyres and the road. Rolling friction is generally taken to mean the friction in the engine, gears and bearings, and sometimes the aerodynamic drag (though sometimes the aerodynamic drag is treated separately). The engine/gears/bearings drag is roughly linear in the speed while the aerodynamic drag is roughly quadratic in the speed.

The bit of the tyres in contact with the road is actually stationary so the friction between the tyre and road is roughly the static friction between the rubber and road, which is constant and doesn't depend on speed.

I've used the word *roughly* a lot because in real life the frictional and aerodynamic losses in cars are complicated and depend on lots of factors.